# Loading RData files within a Rscript

Tags: r, rdata

I am trying to load an .Rdata file within a rscript manipulate the data etc.

when I do this in R console int works:

```
load("R.RData")
x<-Data ##Data is the object in R.data file
```

but when I put this in a script, I get errors:

```
 object of type 'environment' is not subsettable
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an environment and load the data into the environment.

```
tmpenv <- new.env()
load("R.RData", envir=tmpenv)
x <- tmpenv$Data
```

Comment: I also saw a tip on SO that worked like this: `x <- local(get(load("R.RData")))`